# How to move selected Structures, Templates and articles from one liferay instance to another instance?

Tags: portlet, portal, liferay-6

I have 2 separate Liferay Instances, say Instance A which I was running from past 1 year, it has lot of articles, templates and structures, there are 3 different portals running on this same instance.

Now I have a new instance B, I want to move some of the selected articles, structures and templates from Instace A to Instance B. I am not able to find any method to do selected migration.

I can export the articles, structures and templates as a LAR file and import it in Instance B. But the problem is it by default imports all the articles, structures and templates. Is there any way to do selected Import???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. Atleast there is no OOTB way to import selected articles. One option can be, to export the webcontent as lar from the the page itself. For example consider your Page PA on Server SA has a webcontent in webcontent display portlet called WA. Just export the webcontent as lar from the webcontent display portlet itself and then got to the page PB on server SB to import the lar in a webcontent display portlet called WB.

Comment: I tried the method you are suggesting, I think it has some issues. when I tried to move the content between liferay server 6.0 to another instance of 6.0, then it worked, but it failed when I tried the same method to move to 6.1.But anyways I think there is no direct and proper method to move a single page/content, I posted the same in liferay forums too, but no reply.

Comment: Yes one thing about lar is, it is version dependent. LAR exported from one version cannot be imported in another version.

Comment: so, is there any other easy way to move content between 2 different versions of liferay servers?? i searched the forums, what they are suggesting is to take the dump of the database of 6.0 and run some migration scripts, then export to the new database of liferay 6.1. But it is very messy.

Comment: Yes that is the only way. The ideal way is to migrate if you want to completely upgrade from one version to another. It is not that messy, though I would ask you to first do it on your local than on some important servers that matters to you so that you get gist of it. Normally its a very straight process if you are just migrating from one major version to another. You just need to download the latest liferay bundle, update the portal-ext.properties to point old database, move the data folder to the bundle's folder and you should be good to go.